# Troll warning a few next days

Tags: support

I must warn you that a link to this section of StackExchange was published in some popular, but inappropriate Russian resources. There may be a lot of pranksters and   insulters coming in a few next days. Beware false answers.
P.S. Didn't find a way to write directly to moderators.

Comment: We already noticed :) Thanks anyway. Out of curiosity, what would those resources be?

Comment: Many. The problem is - someone wrote article about you, and it got into a net of automated cross-posters. So now twitter, dirty.ru, livejournal, that sort of blogs and agregators. 
That would end in a week, in my experience.

Comment: http://dirty.ru/comments/365232

Comment: Arghh, I've felt that.

Comment: The post is not angry or offensive in itself, though, and meant well. And it seems that some people are trying to help. I'd have to thank the one who did it.

Answer (score 4):

Well a little advertisement won't be much bad for us. Don't worry, we'll be on the lookout for any side effects.

What would certainly help us is that whenever you see a post that you genuinely think to be spam, **flag it** and choose *"it is spam"*.

If it's not spam, but it's something offensive, abusive, etc., then choose *"it is not welcome in our community"*.

**Edit**: I forgot to add. **Don't flag wrong answers**. Vote them down, comment but deciding if an answer ir right or not is not within the moderator duties. We delete not-answers. Flags about answers that are simply wrong but that actually answer the question will be declined.

Comment: I agree. Let's heavily use the tools SE offers us. My apologies to admins in advance :)